# List elements not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Sidebar component.

```
const Sidebar = React.createClass({
  render(){
    let props = this.props;
    return(
      <div className= 'row'>
      <h2>All Rooms</h2>
        <ul>
          {props.rooms.map((room, i) => {
            <li key={i}> {room.name} </li>
          })}
        </ul>
        {props.addingRoom && <input ref='add' />}
      </div>

    );
  }
})
```

This is where I render it populating one room.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App>
  <Sidebar rooms={[ { name: 'First Room'} ]} addingRoom={true} />
  </App>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The contents inside the `<ul></ul>` tag don't render at all. Any idea what I could be missing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from the `map` function, so it renders nothing inside the unordered list. In your [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you do:

```
(room, i) => {
    //statements
}
```

This doesn't return anything. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) requires a callback that returns a value to do anything. `map` transform elements to the array, *mapping* (executing) the callback on each element. The return value is what the value is in the corresponding position in the returned and mapped array.

You must return the list element in the `map` function like so:

```
<ul>
    {props.rooms.map((room, i) => {
      return <li key={i}> {room.name} </li>;
    })}
</ul>
```

Now, the mapped array of list elements is rendered because the list element is returned.

To make this shorter, you may write it in the form `(params) => value` which is equivalent to the above, where `value` is the returned value, like so:

```
{props.room.map((room, i) => <li key={i}> {room.name} </li>)}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the react documentation use "return" in their example? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @mimic Because they are using implicit return syntax (see the second code snippet in my answer). If you write `(params) => value` then `value` is implicitly returned-in the docs' case it's a JSX element.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice there are no curly brackets and it makes the game.